# Running docker compose on windows ubuntu subsystem

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, azure-container-service

I am trying to run docker-compose for this example 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-prepare-app

I have setup Ubuntu subsystem on my windows machines to try out this example. When I run `docker-compose up -d` I get the following error.

> ERROR: Failed to Setup IP tables: Unable to enable NAT rule: 
>   (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s
>   172.19.0.0/16 ! -o br-0fa5c62bc4ce -j MASQUERADE: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

I am running ubuntu subsystem as administration and logged in as root user.
Are there limitations with linux subsystem for updating IP tables?

Answer (score 3):

The WSL subsystem runs on a Microsoft kernel and not a Linux kernel.

Thus many Linux networking commands do not work, iptables is one of them.

There is a discussion with additional information, links, and updated information as it becomes available here - https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/767

As an aside, FWIW, I use this https://github.com/RoliSoft/WSL-Distribution-Switcher

It will install docker images, I have not tried them all, just Fedora so far. I would imagine kernel / network heavy apps you would expect in something such as kali linux would not work although I doubt the kali tools have been tested. Most of the rest of the docker images should work and docker images are probably better optimized for WSL.